# setCoordinate updating after annotation added on my mapView

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

Im adding a bunch of annotations, and sotirng them in an array so i can pull in their new locations and update the map accordingly WITHOUT removing all the annotations first and adding them which causes a flicker. Unfortunately, after their coordinates are initially set and added any setCoordinate call no longer works. Any ideas?

```
- (void)updateMap:(NSData *)responseData {
    //parse out the JSON data
    NSError* error;
    vehicleData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    //find which Dictionary is for our bus.
    for (NSDictionary* route in vehicleData) {
        //find our bus in our vehicles dictionary. Key is by routeID.
        BusPositionDot *busLocationDot; 
        if ([vehicles objectForKey:[route objectForKey:@"RouteID"]] == nil) {
            busLocationDot = [[BusPositionDot alloc] init];
            [vehicles setObject:busLocationDot forKey:[route objectForKey:@"RouteID"]];
            [mapView addAnnotation:[vehicles objectForKey:[route objectForKey:@"RouteID"]]];

        }
        else {
            busLocationDot = [vehicles objectForKey:@"RouteID"];
        }

        float latitude = [[route objectForKey:@"Latitude"] floatValue];
        float longitude = [[route objectForKey:@"Longitude"] floatValue];
        float groundSpeed = [[route objectForKey:@"GroundSpeed"] floatValue];
        float direction = [[route objectForKey:@"Heading"] floatValue];

        float roundedDirection=45 * round(direction/45);

        if(groundSpeed<=3)
            //get view for annotation
            [mapView viewForAnnotation:busLocationDot].image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"buspositiondot.png"];
        else if((roundedDirection==0)||(roundedDirection==360))
            [mapView viewForAnnotation:busLocationDot].image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"buspositiondot0.png"];
        else if(roundedDirection==45)
            [mapView viewForAnnotation:busLocationDot].image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"buspositiondot45.png"];
        else if(roundedDirection==90)
            [mapView viewForAnnotation:busLocationDot].image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"buspositiondot90.png"];
        else if(roundedDirection==135)
            [mapView viewForAnnotation:busLocationDot].image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"buspositiondot135.png"];
        else if(roundedDirection==180)
            [mapView viewForAnnotation:busLocationDot].image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"buspositiondot180.png"];
        else if(roundedDirection==225)
            [mapView viewForAnnotation:busLocationDot].image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"buspositiondot225.png"];
        else if(roundedDirection==270)
            [mapView viewForAnnotation:busLocationDot].image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"buspositiondot270.png"];
        else if(roundedDirection==315)
            [mapView viewForAnnotation:busLocationDot].image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"buspositiondot315.png"];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D currentBusLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
        NSLog(@"setting coord %f & %f",currentBusLocation.latitude,currentBusLocation.longitude);

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            [busLocationDot setCoordinate:currentBusLocation];

        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: When you call `addAnnotation`, you pass `[vehicles objectForKey:[route objectForKey:@"RouteID"]]` but if it already exists, you use `[vehicles objectForKey:@"RouteID"]`.  Why is that?  What happens exactly when `setCoordinate` is called (nothing, crash, other)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reference to this part:

```
if ([vehicles objectForKey:[route objectForKey:@"RouteID"]] == nil) {
    ...
    [mapView addAnnotation:
        [vehicles objectForKey:[route objectForKey:@"RouteID"]]];
}
else {
    busLocationDot = [vehicles objectForKey:@"RouteID"];
}
```

when you call `addAnnotation`, you pass:

```
[vehicles objectForKey:[route objectForKey:@"RouteID"]]
```

but if it already exists, you use:

```
[vehicles objectForKey:@"RouteID"]
```

This means when updating an annotation, a different (most likely wrong) reference is being used.
Either `[vehicles objectForKey:@"RouteID"]` is not actually a `BusPositionDot` or it's not the same instance that was originally added with that "route id".

Therefore, the `setCoordinate` wouldn't work.
Using the same reference when updating the annotation should fix it.

There are a couple of other unrelated, potential issues:

- The code is doing a direct comparison using a `float` variable (eg. `if(roundedDirection==45)`).  This is not recommended even if it "seems to work" -- there's the potential for floating-point precision errors.  Either check if `roundedDirection` is within a very small range of the target value or, in your case, just declare `roundedDirection` as an `int` since it looks like the expression
  `45 * round(direction/45)` will only return values with no fractions.
- The code is setting the `image` of the annotation view directly.  This is ok but make sure the `viewForAnnnotation` delegate method also has the same exact logic to set the `image` based on direction otherwise what may happen is the annotation view's image will get reset to some default when panning or zooming.  You may need to add a `direction` property to `BusPositionDot`.